# apple devices doesn't render font

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use rare font on my site, which called HeliosThin. I store this font in the following folder

```
resouces/static/fonts/font.TTF
```

And then I add it to my css file like this:

```
body {
    font-family: 'HeliousThin' !important;
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"HeliousThin";
    src: url("../fonts/font.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

And it works fine on my local machine and on the server side when I use linux or windows or android. But when i open my site on the apple devices fonts doesn't render.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of iOS does it not work on? 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf

Comment: i used macbook, iphone 6 and ipad 1 with ios 5, font just doesn't show

Comment: Does the text render and just not in the correct font? or no text at all?

Comment: does not render if font is HeliousThin, when I remove it in firebug it appears with standart font

Comment: In the link I provided, support for TTF starts with iOS7. I would try using a different font, a web service, or you may be able to convert the font to OTF. OTF is a good format to use, SVG would be best.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf

Answer (score 0):

According to this link (look at the tab browser compatibility)

http://everythingfonts.com/font-face

ios doesn't support ttf only svg. You are better off using the trick specified in the page above i.e. listing eot, ttf, svg and let the browser pick the ones that is supported.